# (Instagram API) Get the list of instagram users this user is followed by

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I want to get the list of instagram users this user is followed by.(but not for myself, for another user).

I do API call GET

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/4234233244/followed-by.json?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

like this

```
/v1/users/user_id/followed-by.json?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

But I receive following response

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"APINotAllowedError","code":400,"error_message":"you cannot view this resource"}}
```

Why? How can I do that? I set up `follower_list` permission scope(Actually all scopes `scope=basic+follower_list+public_content+relationships+likes+comments`).
And He's not a private user, I think so ;). And my dev app is in Sandbox mode, and this user was added to to the Sandbox, so I can get his profile information.

I know

> Deprecation of /users/USER-ID/follows and /users/USER-ID/followed-by

But what should I do? I try to develop a great instagram client for tablet :)

Answer (score 4):

I dont think you can get other user's follower list/following list anymore. You can only get the list for the logged in user.

Here is documentation: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/followed-by?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

you can only get list for `self`, not any id

Comment: Have any ideas, how to efficiently get necessary information, because origin instagram client provides it.

Comment: The logged user you mentioned, is the user of the instagram developer account? If it is, is it possible to make it dynamically? Include some login to get any user permission?

Comment: it can be made dynamic, any user can login to your app and see their followers/following, this will be possible only after you app is reviewed and gone live, in sandbox mode you can only test with the developer account and the response will only have users in your sandbox

Comment: This endpoint has been retired. How can we get the list of follower now

Comment: @Arif did you get any alternative

Answer (score 0):

List of users who your user follow :

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

List of users who your user is being followed by :

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/followed-by?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

List of recent media from your user :

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

List of recent media from other users :

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-Id}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

More information at [Instagram Endpoint Reference](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/)

in left pane (below `Endpints` button) you will see a list of media types, each one corresponding to a page that explains all related api Interfaces.

Comment: This will work **just** for *self* user; it won't work with the user-id *4234233244* as the OP asked – That use is deprecated. There is no way to know the list of *"followed-by"* for a user.